# How to get installed application shortcuts from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension replaces new tab page with the one I wrote. But if I install an extension has an app shortcut (the one appears in default new tab page), I naturally can not access this shortcut. So is there any way to get these shortcuts from api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for; [chrome.management.getAll](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-getAll).